# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '30.0' when running unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, airflow

I'm trying to run a test that was previously working but has suddenly stopped running but now i seem to get an error on all my tests e.g.

```
from httmock import HTTMock
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch, call, mock_open, MagicMock, Mock, ANY

import os.path
import os


from src.operators import InjestDictDescriptionOperator
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook
from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook

class TestInjestDictDescriptionOperator(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # hook patches
        self.open_file_mock = patch('builtins.open').start()
        self.os_path_isdir = patch.object(os.path, 'isdir').start()
        self.os_makedirs = patch.object(os, 'makedirs').start()
        self.open_file_write_mock = self.open_file_mock.return_value.__enter__.return_value.write


        # prepare the target
        self.target = InjestDictDescriptionOperator(
            task_id='InjestDictDescriptionOperatorTest',
            sql=None,
            postgres_conn_id='test',
            aws_conn_id='s3-conn-1',
            s3_bucket_name=‘data’,
            output_path='output/path/1')

    def tearDown(self):
        patch.stopall()

    def testTmpFolderCreationIfItDoesntExist(self):
        self.os_path_isdir.return_value = False
        self.target.execute(None)
        self.os_makedirs.assert_called_with('/tmp/')

    def testTmpFolderNotCreatedIfItExists(self):
        self.os_path_isdir.return_value = True
        self.target.execute(None)
        self.os_makedirs.assert_not_called()

    def testTmpFileCreation(self):
        self.target.execute(None)
        self.open_file_mock.assert_called_with(
            '/tmp/modelling/temp.txt',
            'w+',
            encoding='utf-8')

    def testTmpFileDataDump(self):
        self.target.execute(None)
        self.open_file_write_mock.assert_has_calls(
            [ call(f"{doc['name']}\n") for doc in self.dummy_data ]
            , any_order=False)
```

The traceback details of the problem are

```
ests/operators/modelling/language/test_injest_dict_description_operator.py:9: in <module>
    from src.operators.modelling.language import InjestDictDescriptionOperator
src/operators/modelling/language/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from .injest_onboarded_commands_operator import Operator as InjestOnboardedCommandsOperator
src/operators/modelling/language/injest_onboarded_commands_operator.py:9: in <module>
    from airflow.models import BaseOperator
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py:50: in <module>
    from airflow.models import DAG  # noqa: E402
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py:21: in <module>
    from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator, BaseOperatorLink  # noqa: F401
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py:43: in <module>
    from airflow.models.dag import DAG
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py:52: in <module>
    from airflow.models.dagbag import DagBag
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py:50: in <module>
    class DagBag(BaseDagBag, LoggingMixin):
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py:80: in DagBag
    DAGBAG_IMPORT_TIMEOUT = conf.getint('core', 'DAGBAG_IMPORT_TIMEOUT')
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:414: in getint
    return int(self.get(section, key, **kwargs))
E   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '30.0'collection failure
tests/operators/modelling/language/test_injest_dict_description_operator.py:9: in <module>
    from src.operators.modelling.language import InjestDictDescriptionOperator
src/operators/modelling/language/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from .injest_onboarded_commands_operator import Operator as InjestOnboardedCommandsOperator
src/operators/modelling/language/injest_onboarded_commands_operator.py:9: in <module>
    from airflow.models import BaseOperator
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py:50: in <module>
    from airflow.models import DAG  # noqa: E402
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py:21: in <module>
    from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator, BaseOperatorLink  # noqa: F401
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py:43: in <module>
    from airflow.models.dag import DAG
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py:52: in <module>
    from airflow.models.dagbag import DagBag
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py:50: in <module>
    class DagBag(BaseDagBag, LoggingMixin):
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py:80: in DagBag
    DAGBAG_IMPORT_TIMEOUT = conf.getint('core', 'DAGBAG_IMPORT_TIMEOUT')
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:414: in getint
    return int(self.get(section, key, **kwargs))
E   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '30.0'
```

The only thing that changed was apache-airflow. I upgraded to the latest version 2.0 but then realised i would need to refactor parts of my code so downgraded to a later version.

Comment: This may have been caused by pytest 5.4.3 being installed

Comment: It looks like you have a configuration file from a different version. Can you delete the ~ / airflow / airflow.cfg file?

Comment: The DAGBAG_IMPORT_TIMEOUT had been upgraded in the config files to float for 2.0 and for 1.10.14 it needed to be float.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The DAGBAG_IMPORT_TIMEOUT had been upgraded in the config files to float for 2.0 and for 1.10.14 it needed to be float.

Deleted airflow completely including cfg files and re-installed the version

Answer (score 22):

Happened to me after I installed Airflow 2 on accident and then downgraded to 1.10.12.  Solution was to remove ~/airflow after the downgrade and let it re-create since this is just my test machine.

Comment: you sir are a legend!

Comment: You can do `echo $AIRFLOW_HOME` to figure out where the folder is located. It can be difficult to find for those using Ubuntu on Windows 10, as it might have landed in the Windows documents depending on how the Airflow package was first installed

Answer (score 6):

Update the `airflow.cfg` file. Search for the variable `dagbag_import_timeout` and update it's value type to integer instead of float, from `dagbag_import_timeout = 30.0` to `dagbag_import_timeout = 30`. This should work fine.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Worked for me but I needed to pip install psycopg2 and apache-airflow-providers-postgres as well (maybe because I already had some dags using postgres).